# MS Visio Shape name with properties

Tags: replace, properties, shapes, visio

I have a layout file with a warehouse bin storing system (only one level), I have combined the shapes with dimensions on the layout, the visio file with an outer excel data (there are multiple properties, but only Reference no. - Reference number is important to us at this stage only).

Now I need to make for example a macro or any other solution to:
1) copy the property internal number,
2) edit the shape name,
3) make a new line below the name,
4) paste the copied property.

And do that to all shapes named from A1001-A2162, B1001-B2208, C1001-C2276, X1001-X1025, Z1001-Z2087.

Can somebody please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to not use the name of the shape. It just brings confusion where there is no need to (Name versus universal name, the name being unique on one page, etc.).
Rather use a custom property and name it "Name". This new property can now be edited in the shape data window.

For displaying the properties (Reference number and name) you have several possibilities.

Either use the shape's text (Hit F2, then use the insert menu to insert the desired fields),

or use Visio's data graphics.

For labelling a lot of shapes you can of course write a macro (use the macro recorder on one shape, then make it generic by replacing the specific shape information by general ones),

but I would rahter use the built in functions:
1) in the case of using the shape's text, set up a master having the labels already prepared, then use it for your drawing.
2) in the case of data graphics, just select all the relevant shapes and apply the data graphics. This will label them all in one operation.